# rollmean and sparse daily samples of some measure

Tags: r

I had a look at the [rollmean](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/zoo/versions/1.8-4/topics/rollmean) doc and did quite a lot of Google searches. However, what is still not clear for me is whether rollmean can be easily applied to sparse samples, i.e. were we only have intermittent daily measures like in  this snapshot of daily measurements of temperatures ordered by date:

```
Date Temperature
2013/01/01 10
2013/01/01 20
2013/01/03 15
2013/01/04 15
2013/01/10 15
2013/01/10 15
...
```

Can I simply do:

```
X <- Temperatures %>%
  select(Date, Temperature) %>%
  mutate(temp_ma = rollmean(Temperature, k = 12, fill = NA, align = "right"))
```

as discussed [here](http://uc-r.github.io/ts_moving_averages).

PS:

I include a reproducible data example:

```
n <- 200
dates <- sample(seq(as.Date('2000/01/01'), as.Date('2000/12/31'), by="day"), n)
ys <- x <- rnorm(n, 100, 25)

df <- data.frame(dates, ys)

ggplot(df, aes(x=dates, y=ys)) +
    geom_line()
```

How can I create a 30 day moving average in this scenario please as an example?

Comment: What's your expected output? It's not clear to me what you expect.

Comment: appreciate your comment. i know i should produce reproducible example but imho this is quite difficult in this case. is it really not clear? I start at 2013/01/01 and go until let us say 2014/01/01 and would like to calculated the MA given k given the sparse data.

Comment: Yes that I get, but do you need two truly consecutive dates to be averaged? If this is the case you need imo to fill the missing date, with NA, for example, then average with rollmean

Comment: So you'll need to join this data with a complete set of dates..

Comment: OK thanks so use NA for any dates where I do not have a measurement? I probably do this in SQL (-;

Comment: Yes, that's what I'd do at least. You decide if you want to use `na.rm=T` or not with `rollmean`

Comment: If you are going to fill with NA, and then use `na.rm=TRUE`, wouldn't that be equivalent to just taking the mean of the current, sparse data?